# Azure DevOps migrate TFS projects to same Git repository

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

On TFS/TFVC I have this project with these branches:

```
|_ProjectAbc
    |__ProjectAbc_Main
    |__ProjectAbc_Dev
```

Now I'm migrating all my TFS projects to Git using the Azure DevOps Portal.

There I click on "Import Repository" and choose to import from TFVC. At this is all fine.

[image]

But the "Import Repository" don't recognise and separate the branches.

My idea is to create a Git repository by importing the `ProjectAbc_Main` branch to be the `master` and then create a branch based on `master` to be my `DEV` branch.

But I want to import my TFS `ProjectAbc_Dev` branch to my Git `DEV` branch and include all the history too.

How can I do that?

I can change my Git `DEV` branch with the TFS `ProjectAbc_Dev` branch and then sync the branch, but with this I loose my `ProjectAbc_Dev` history and I want to keep the history.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with AzureDevOps migration tool that support only simple cases.

You should use a tool like [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) to be able todo that: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md#fetch-all-the-history-for-all-branches

Comment: Before I had tried that solution but I was always having authentication errors and I didn't know why, so I gave it up. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ninita Maybe that could help: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/TF400813-error-with-visualstudio.com.md